# Xamarin.Android build error: duplicate class R.java

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

I loaded a [long-dormant Xamarin.Android project](https://github.com/patridge/MonoForAndroidFlashlight/) that I last opened in MonoDevelop, when it was  still called Mono for Android. Every time I tried to build the project, debug or release, it fails with "Error: duplicate class" pointing to R.java.

Since R.java is just an auto-generated file for the various project resources, I tried editing a filename and letting Xamarin Studio update the file. This didn't resolve the build error.

Similar searches find issues with improperly named IDs in an axml file, but all the IDs in this project appear to meet Android requirements (and it built fine the last time I worked on it to generate the [project's APK](http://bit.ly/monoflash)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Deleting the project's bin and obj folders entirely and letting them be rebuilt from scratch resolved the build error just fine.

Since the actual R.java file is buried deep in the obj folder, it may have been possible to be a little less eager with the deletes. There is probably a better solution entirely, but this certainly got the job done.

Answer (score 1):

1. delete all files and folders from your c:\users\\appdata\local\xamarin\
2. Restart VS - very important
3. Clean Solution
4. Build / Rebuild solution

**If the above ends up with some other resource errors , close and reopen VS and repeat steps 2,3,4.**